# Main gui is not opening

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a password manager, I want it to be able to create accounts and store passwords for different separately. Everything works well until I get to logging in with the account i created. Nothing happens when the submit button is supposed to open the main gui. This is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import json
import os

PASSWORD_LIBRARY_FILENAME = "password_library.json"

class PasswordManagerGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Password Manager")

        # Initialize password library
        self.password_library = {}
        self.load_password_library()

        # Create the login page
        self.login_page()

        # Bind the submit button to the check_password() method
        self.submit_button.bind("<Button-1>", self.check_password)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def load_password_library(self):
        if os.path.exists(PASSWORD_LIBRARY_FILENAME):
            with open(PASSWORD_LIBRARY_FILENAME, 'r') as file:
                self.password_library = json.load(file)
        else:
            self.password_library = {}

    def save_password_library(self):
        with open(PASSWORD_LIBRARY_FILENAME, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(self.password_library, file)

    # Methods for handling file menu commands
    def new_file(self):
        self.create_account()

    def open_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension=".json",
                                               filetypes=[("JSON files", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")])
        if file_path:
            with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
                self.password_library = json.load(file)

    def save_file(self):
        self.save_password_library()

    # Create password page to access the rest of the program
    def login_page(self):
        # Create a new window for the login page
        self.login_window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.login_window.title("Login")

        # Add a username entry field to the login window
        self.username_label = tk.Label(self.login_window, text="Enter Username:")
        self.username_label.pack(pady=10)
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.login_window)
        self.username_entry.pack(pady=5)

        # Add a password entry field to the login window
        self.password_label = tk.Label(self.login_window, text="Enter Password:")
        self.password_label.pack(pady=10)
        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self.login_window, show="*")
        self.password_entry.pack(pady=5)

        # Add a button to the login window to submit the username and password
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self.login_window, text="Submit", command=self.check_password)
        self.submit_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Add a button to the login window to create a new account
        self.create_account_button = tk.Button(self.login_window, text="Create Account", command=self.create_account)
        self.create_account_button.pack(pady=5)


    def create_account(self):
        # Create a new window for creating a new account
        self.create_account_window = tk.Toplevel(self.login_window)
        self.create_account_window.title("Create Account")

        # Add a label and entry field for the new username
        self.username_label = tk.Label(self.create_account_window, text="Enter Username:")
        self.username_label.pack(pady=10)
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.create_account_window)
        self.username_entry.pack(pady=5)

        # Add a label and entry field for the new password
        self.new_password_label = tk.Label(self.create_account_window, text="Enter New Password:")
        self.new_password_label.pack(pady=10)
        self.new_password_entry = tk.Entry(self.create_account_window, show="*")
        self.new_password_entry.pack(pady=5)

        # Add a label and entry field to confirm the new password
        self.confirm_password_label = tk.Label(self.create_account_window, text="Confirm Password:")
        self.confirm_password_label.pack(pady=10)
        self.confirm_password_entry = tk.Entry(self.create_account_window, show="*")
        self.confirm_password_entry.pack(pady=5)

        # Add a button to submit the new account information
        self.submit_account_button = tk.Button(self.create_account_window, text="Submit", command=self.add_new_account)
        self.submit_account_button.pack(pady=10)

    def add_new_account(self):
        # Get the new username and password from the entry fields
        new_username = self.username_entry.get()
        new_password = self.new_password_entry.get()
        confirm_password = self.confirm_password_entry.get()

        # Check if the passwords match
        if new_password != confirm_password:
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Passwords do not match. Please try again.")
            return

        # Code for adding new account goes here

        # Close the create account window and display a message
        self.create_account_window.destroy()
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Account Created", "Your new account has been created.")

    def check_password(self):
        # Get the username and password entered by the user
        username = self.username_entry.get()
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        # Check if the username and password are correct
        if username in self.password_library and self.password_library[username]["password"] == password:
            # Destroy the login page window
            self.login_window.destroy()

            # Open the main GUI window
            self.create_main_gui(username)
        else:
            # Display an error message and clear the username and password entry fields
            self.username_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.password_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Incorrect username or password. Please try again.")

    def create_main_gui(self, username):
        self.current_username = username
        self.current_passwords = self.password_library[username]["accounts"]

        # Create label for displaying instructions
        self.instructions_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Enter a new password or retrieve an existing one:")
        self.instructions_label.pack(pady=10)

        # Create entry widget for entering website or service name
        self.website_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Website or Service:")
        self.website_label.pack()
        self.website_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.website_entry.pack(pady=5)

        # Create entry widget for entering username or email
        self.username_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Username or Email:")
        self.username_label.pack()
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.username_entry.pack(pady=5)

        # Create entry widget for entering password
        self.password_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Password:")
        self.password_label.pack()
        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, show="*")
        self.password_entry.pack(pady=5)

        # Create button for adding password to the manager
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Add Password", command=self.add_password)
        self.add_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Create button for retrieving password from the manager
        self.retrieve_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Retrieve Password", command=self.retrieve_password)
        self.retrieve_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Create button for displaying all passwords
        self.show_all_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Show All Passwords", command=self.show_all_passwords)
        self.show_all_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Add a button for editing password in the manager
        self.edit_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Edit Password", command=self.edit_password)
        self.edit_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Add a button for deleting password from the manager
        self.delete_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Delete Password", command=self.delete_password)
        self.delete_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Create a menu bar
        self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self.root)

        # Create a file menu
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.new_file)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.open_file)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_file)
        self.file_menu.add_separator()
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.root.quit)

        # Add the file menu to the menu bar
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)

        # Add the menu bar to the root window
        self.root.config(menu=self.menu_bar)
        
        self.root.mainloop()


    
    def add_password(self):
        # Get data from entry widgets
        website = self.website_entry.get()
        username = self.username_entry.get()
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        # Code for adding password to manager goes here
        
        # Clear entry widgets
        self.website_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.username_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.password_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    
    def retrieve_password(self):
        # Get data from entry widgets
        website = self.website_entry.get()
        username = self.username_entry.get()

        # Code for retrieving password from manager goes here
        password = "password"  # Placeholder for retrieved password

        if password is None:
            # If password is not found, display an error message
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Password not found.")
        else:
            # If password is found, display the password in the password entry widget
            self.password_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.password_entry.insert(0, password)

    def delete_password(self):
        website = self.website_entry.get()

        if website:
            if website in self.current_passwords:
                del self.current_passwords[website]
                self.save_password_library()
            else:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Website not found in the password library.")
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please enter the website to delete the password.")

    def edit_password(self):
        website = self.website_entry.get()
        new_username = self.username_entry.get()
        new_password = self.password_entry.get()

        if website and new_username and new_password:
            if website in self.current_passwords:
                self.current_passwords[website] = {"username": new_username, "password": new_password}
                self.save_password_library()
            else:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Website not found in the password library.")
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please fill in all the fields to edit the password.")


    def show_all_passwords(self):
        # Code for retrieving all passwords from manager goes here
        passwords = {"google.com": {"username": "john.doe", "password": "password123"},
                    "facebook.com": {"username": "jane.doe", "password": "password456"},
                    "twitter.com": {"username": "johndoe", "password": "password789"}}

        # Create a new window to display all passwords
        self.password_list_window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.password_list_window.title("All Passwords")

        # Create a label to display the passwords
        password_text = "Website\t\tUsername\t\tPassword\n\n"
        for website, data in passwords.items():
            username = data["username"]
            password = data["password"]
            password_text += f"{website}\t\t{username}\t\t{password}\n"

        password_label = tk.Label(self.password_list_window, text=password_text)
        password_label.pack(pady=10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pm_gui = PasswordManagerGUI()
```

Ive tried changing a lot to try and link the submit button to the check account function but theres no change when its run

Comment: Remember that `self.root.mainloop()` will not return until the main window is closed.

Comment: It would help if you trimmed this code down to a [mcve]. Most of the code isn't necessary to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two calls to `self.root.mainloop()`, which can cause issues...

Generally a better approach is to have your application's main class (`PasswordManagerGUI` in this case), inherit from `tk.Tk()` like so:

```
class PasswordManagerGUI(tk.Tk):  # this class inherits from 'tk.Tk'
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # initialize Tk
        # self.root = tk.Tk() <- this can go away since inheritance takes care of it!
        self.title("Password Manager")  # references to 'self.root' just become 'self'

        # Initialize password library
        self.password_library = {}
        self.load_password_library()

        # Create the login page
        self.login_page()

        # Bind the submit button to the check_password() method
        self.submit_button.bind("<Button-1>", self.check_password)

        # self.root.mainloop()  # we'll call 'mainloop' in the guard clause below...
```

Then you'll typically instantiate and start your app in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard clause at the end of your app

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pm_gui = PasswordManagerGUI()  # you already had this!
    pm_gui.mainloop()  # so just add this to start your app!
```

To finish making this change, you'll need to replace all instances of `self.root` with `self`.

You should also remove the call to `self.root.mainloop()` from `create_main_gui`.